# Creating part programmatically not working in kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-kepler

I'm creating one RCP application in Juno.

In that app I'm creating programmatically Part based on `PartDescriptor` like following.

```
 MPart part = partService.createPart("discripto.id");
 part.setElementId("element.id");
```

And it was working perfectly till Eclipse 4.2.2.

Same code when I'm trying to run in Eclipse Kepler, its not throwing any exception view is comes like following without any control:

[image]

Can any one please tell me what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find answer just after posting question:

**Problem:**

`@PostConstruct` annotated method is not called

**Solution:**  from [Why isn't my @Inject-able/@PostConstruct methods being injected?](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/FAQ#Why_isn.27t_my_.40Inject-able.2F.40PostConstruct_methods_being_injected.3F)

> There are typically two reasons why injection fails.
>
> **Mismatched Annotations:** Ensure your bundles use **Import-Package** with a package version to pull in the standard annotations rather than a **Require-Bundle** on the `javax.annotation` bundle.
>
> ```
> Import-Package: javax.inject;version="1.0.0",javax.annotation; version="1.0.0"
> ```
>
> **Unresolvable Injections:** The injector attempts to resolve objects in the context. If an object cannot be resolved in the context, and it's not marked as `@Optional`, then the method will not be injected. The injector does not normally log when such situations occur as it is an expected occurrence.

My problem is because of the FIRST one.